# Font used in mathematical papers in Elsevier journals

Tags: fonts

The font in mathematical papers of Elsevier is elegant, as the figure below shows. I'd like to know the name of this font, that contains paconte and the command to call it.

[image]

For those who have access to a link to the PDF article is [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885064X10000919).

I suspect that this font is protected by copyright and therefore there is a free package it. If this is the case then I would like a font in a free package available.

Is that possible?

Comment: So your question is whether you can duplicate the title? That is, the ARTICLE INFO and ABSTRACT?

Comment: @Werner: I think the question is "What is this font?"

Comment: Elsevier likes to claim its journals are expensive because of the 'added value' it brings to scientific papers. That's questionable. And if anyone thinks this font contributes 'added value' to Elsevier publications, it deserves to be called Gullible.

Comment: The very first thing to do: In AcroReader right click on the document and go to the `Document Properties->Fonts` tab. It will show you the fonts used in the document `t1-gul-....` are the ones that you are after. @JohnBaez Welcome to TeX.SX even if you were just ranting by :)

Comment: @Ruben - I don't understand why this posting was closed as a duplicate of [some other query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5001), which actually appears to have been posted *somewhat later* than the present, now-closed query. For sure, none of the answers provided under that other posting help solve the OP's question, which was about the (math, but presumably also text) font that is in use at some (but not all) journals in the Elsevier group of journals.

Comment: I'd like to see this posting re-opened, as the questions raised above go beyond the standard "what font is this" query.

Comment: Recently it appears that Elsevier has changed the font in many of its journals, from the mentioned Gulliver to one almost perfectly matching the free font Charis SIL. In fact, Adobe Acrobat reveals that Charis SIL is used in some portions of the heading. I have made a comparison here: https://i.imgur.com/1kYpNZT.png 

In light of this, I believe this question should be re-opened, as the current answers may be outdated and future people finding this question could benefit from the knowledge of Charis SIL being available as an alternative.

Comment: @Mico (forgot to mention) Also, math portions appear to be typeset now with the free STIX 2.0 font, and thus the user could use both Charis SIL and STIX 2.0 with XeLaTeX to match Elsevier typesetting choices, if he/she so desires, something that was not possible when they used the proprietary Gulliver.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to some information on the webpage [The `elsarticle` LaTeX document class](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle), the font used by most Elsevier journals is called **Gulliver**. The designer of this font is Gerard Unger.

More information about this font may be found at [this website](http://www.gerardunger.com/fontstore/store-gulliver.html). This font is proprietary, and I'm not aware of any "free" copies of this font. In particular, there's no LaTeX font package that lets you load the Gulliver font.

Answer (score 21):

It's Gerard Unger's Gulliver. [Furthermore](http://www.myfonts.com/newsletters/cc/201106.html),

> Ownership of Gulliver is a somewhat exclusive business. Unger only sells it through his own site, and at a minimum of twenty licenses a time to “organisations and companies whose printing work will do justice to its space-saving capabilities.”

Try [BT Charter](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/charterbt/) as a substitute.

Comment: +1 for "Kill Unger's business". I suspect that "... a minimum of twenty licences at a time ..." is grossly insulting and inconsiderate for many TeX.SX participants.

Comment: Space saving? I think this journal has saved too much space with the font. The line width is way too long for effortless reading.

Comment: "To guarantee Gulliver’s exclusivity, no more than 100 licences will be issued worldwide. Licensees automatically become members of the Gulliver Club." Interesting attitude...

Answer (score 2):

You can try taking a high definition snapshot of a line or two of the text and see if http://www.whatfontis.com/ or http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ can yield you a font that is similar enough. I tried it with the screenshot provided, but the results were less than optimal (the first link provided me with a list of 100 possible matches, but none seemed good enough, and the second one just gave an error).

Comment: Given a PDF, one can get a list of its embedded fonts. Doing this on a different Elsevier journal article led me to believe they're using some proprietary commercial fonts (names like AdvEls-ent1, AdvEls-ent2, etc.). Using a better quality image (around 1250 pixels wide containing 19 of the 26 lowercase letters)  at both font sites didn't return any perfect matches, though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all lets clarify some things. Elsevier is a publishing company which holds copy rights for many mathematical journals which it distributes through ScienceDirect database. The article you pulled out is from the [Journal of Complexity](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-complexity/). Have you bothered to check [Guide to authors](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/622865/authorinstructions)? You will be able to find [Elsevier LaTeX document class](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/latex). Whether the fonts in that class correspond to fonts you see in the printed version depends on their production process. I would not be surprised at all that the Journal in question uses proprietary fonts for the final version. By the way the articles do not have to be submitted in LaTeX which is another indication that they use proprietary fonts.

Comment: I'm digging out an old question here... I totally agree with your answer: the elsarticle.cls or the cas-dc.cls classes recommended in the Guide to authors of many Elsevier journals (NIM-A and B at least) use STIX Two while the final prints seem to be using Charis for text and STIX for math.

Comment: @CedricH. It seems you are correct. I compared the math font of PDF created by Elsevier (2023) compared it with STIX (not stix two). They are almost the same, although there are slight differences.