# Space between letter and lowercase in latex math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts

is there a way to remove the space between the variable and the lowercase letter as standard in math environment?

by now i'm using this:

```
\begin{equation}
a\;b_{\! c}\;d
\end{equation}
```

Without `\!` the space looks to big. Now i thought, if it is possible to set this by default in the math environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The spacing without the `\!` seems correct for the product. If you are looking for more of a row vector, see if `\begin{matrix} a & b_{c} & d \end{matrix}` is more to your liking.

Comment: no no, its for normal equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remember that (La)TeX was designed carefully by people who know much, much more than we'll ever learn about typesetting. Changing such rather common constructions is ill-advised. Maybe in some specific case the default isn't ideal.

Comment: I agree with this answer - I've worked in mathematics and physics for a long time, and the standard spacing is the norm. You might also like to read the comments on a similar question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63519/problematic-space-between-s-and-its-subscript?rq=1)

Comment: generally i'm not trying to change the common constructions, but in my case i thought it was looking better.
i will use the standard spacing then.

thanks for the answers