# how to achieve the journal style shown in the screenshot?

Tags: elsarticle, journal

[image]
Means help me i want to write these all things with perfect setting..

Comment: Welcome, use the template provided by Elsevier.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using the [elsarticle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/) document class.

Do be aware, though, that you will almost certainly *not* be able to perfectly reproduce the screenshot you've posted, even if you do use the `elsarticle` document class. For one, the logos at the top of the first page are proprietary to Elsevier; I highly doubt Elsevier licenses the use of its logos -- except by very special arrangement... Second, most Elsevier journals use a proprietary font called `Gulliver`, which was designed by Gerard Unger. For more on this font, see the posting [Font used in mathematical papers in Elsevier journals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45908/5001).