# change the font type to Arial (or Helvetica) for an Elsevier paper

Tags: fonts, elsarticle, publishing

I'm preparing a paper to send my first paper to one of the Elsevier journals. I use Texmaker to format my manuscript with Elsevier article class (elsarticle.cls). From the "Guide for Authors", the instruction about the type of the font is to use 
one of the following types:

Arial of (Helvetica)

Courier

Symbol

Times

Most of Elsevier paper use Arial font, now I changed my font to Arial using the following source code:

```
\documentclass[5p,times,twocolumn,8pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%end

% declarations for front matter
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Functional magnetic resonance imaging (fMRI) has become the standard technique in functional brain imaging. It is a noninvasive, radiation-free technique that has good temporal and spatial reso- lution. The fMRI technique is based on detection of the decrease in deoxyhemoglobin concentration at the site of neuronal activ- ity, which causes a local increase in the magnetic resonance signal. This effect has been termed the blood oxygenation level depend- ent (BOLD) contrast mechanism [1,2]. In essence, blood serves as its own contrast agent in fMRI and allows identification of active brain sites. BOLD fMRI generally capitalizes on the differ- ence between two states: an active on-state in which stimulus related neural activity is generated and a passive off-state in which stimulus-related neural activity is absent or kept to a minimum. By comparing the active on-state to the passive off-state, the resultant difference defines the site, volume, and level of fMRI activation. FMRI data go through two main processing stages. First, BOLD

% Table 
\end{document}
```

but it does not matches the font in Elsevier published versions:
[image]

Knowing that there is an instruction says : make sure that you only use the recommended fonts (**Type1 or TrueType**) (previously cited), I don't know what **Type1 or TrueType** means.

Comment: Microsoft ships Arial as a TrueType font. You can see it is `arial.ttf`.

Comment: Elsevier journals use custom (and rather proprietary) text and math fonts, such as "Gulliver", a font (family) designed by Gerard Unger. There's no way you're going to match Elsevier's proprietary sans-serif font with Arial or Helvetica. For more information on Elsevier fonts, see the postings [how to achieve the journal style shown in the screenshot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334681/5001) and [Font used in mathematical papers in Elsevier journals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45908/5001).

Comment: If you want your text font to be Arial, you should do `\setmainfont{Arial}`, but it seems to be the worst ever font to use for body text.

Comment: Two separate comments: (i) I don't believe the `elsarticle` document class recognizes the option `8pt`. (ii) Don't load both `graphics` and `graphicx`; loading the latter should suffice fully.

Comment: Also, don't employ the option `times` with `elsarticle`: that option instructs LaTeX to load the deprecated `txfonts` font package. I suggest that if you want to use Times Roman text and math fonts -- remember, Elsevier journals use their own proprietary fonts, which do not look like Times Roman ... -- in the document *to be submitted to some Elsevier-class journal*, that you load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages. And, issue the instruction `\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet}`if you wish to load an Helvetica clone for the sans-serif font, scaled to match the x-height of Times Roman.

Comment: @ Mico, as I said before, this my first paper  I am trying to do as little as possible on the layout so that it looks like the published versions. So I understand from your comments that the final shape of the paper is made by the editorial office of the journal

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, few (if any!) Elsevier journals will accept manuscripts that require XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for successful compilation. Hence, don't go the `fontspec` route unless you have explicit permission from the editor that it's OK to do so.

My first piece of advice would be: Just use the default (Computer modern) fonts for the manuscript you are about to submit to an Elsevier journal. Most Elsevier journals use a proprietary font (named Gulliver) for the final, typeset product. Any time you spend on selecting a font other than Computer Modern is likely to be wasted.

If, for some reason, you do not wish to use Computer Modern for the manuscript you're about to submit to an Elsevier journal, my next piece of advice is: don't go overboard when it comes to specifying fonts while using the `elsarticle` document class. For sure, though, I would not use the `times` option, since doing so will load the deprecated `txfonts` font package. Instead, load the newer `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages in the preamble, via `\usepackage` instructions. And, if you wish to adorn your document with an Helvetica clone, issue the instruction `\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet}` to load the font scaled so that its x-height matches that of Times Roman.

If you insist, you could load the package `courier` to replace the default monospaced font (`Computer Modern TT`) with `Courier`. That said, I think it's fair to say that Courier does not mix-and-match particularly well with either Times Roman or Helvetica. Don't use it; go with the default Computer Modern TT monospaced font instead.

Finally, the `elsarticle` document class doesn't recognize the option `8pt`; it'll be ignored.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet}
%\usepackage{courier} % not really recommended
\begin{document}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, 
sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non 
justo. 

$E=mc^2$

Hello\textsf{Hello}\texttt{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

The only important command is `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}`. You have to use it for all TeX engines

Comment: Since it's not clear which Elsevier journals (if any!) currently accept manuscripts that require XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for compilation, I'm not sure it's good advice to provide a solution which requires the `fontspec` package.

Comment: I used the preamble which was given by the original post! And I didn't gave any adevice to use `lualatex` or `xelatex`!

Comment: If one loads the `fontspec` package, one *must* use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, no?

Comment: in the original post is `fontspec` loaded and that is what I used, too.

Comment: To me, it looks like the OP was rather unsure about what to do w.r.t. loading `Arial` (or `Helvetica`). I suspect that he/she must have read somewhere about the `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` directives, not realizing that Elsevier-stable journals -- why else use the `elsarticle` document class?! -- are not known for letting authors submit documents which can only be compiled with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: why do you discuss this with _me_ and not the OP??

Comment: I'm trying to have a discussion with both you and the OP. I've left commens below the initial query; so far, though, the OP hasn't responded.