# text font similar to Gulliver

Tags: fonts, packages

I want to make journal tempalet using Gulliver font, but since it doesn't exist in latex package, what should I use package text font in latex similar to Gulliver ??

Comment: See this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45908/font-used-in-mathematical-papers-in-elsevier-journals